# How to use ignoredProperties with multiple vars?

Tags: swift, realm

I'm trying to use `ignoredProperties` in `Realm` model. Is this code right?

```
class Train: RLMObject {
    dynamic var arrival = ""
    dynamic var arrivalToShow = ""
    dynamic var departureToShow = ""

    func ignoredProperties() -> NSArray {
        let propertiesToIgnore = [arrivalToShow, departureToShow]
        return propertiesToIgnore
    }
}
```

Comment: Some context would be nice. Are you using some third party library where the method ignoredProperties() has special meaning?

And have you tried your code? Does it have the desired effect?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not *exactly* right, even when it compiles. ;)

1. `ignoredProperties` has to be declared as overridden class function.
2. Don't return the property values, but instead the property names as strings by putting them in quotation marks.

This would look then like below:

```
    override class func ignoredProperties() -> [AnyObject] {
        return ["arrivalToShow", "departureToShow"]
    }
```

Comment: but only my code compiles, overriden function does not compile (

Comment: You're right. Specifying `NSArray` as return type was only valid until Swift 1.1, where implicit bridging casts were applied. Thanks for pointing out. I corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

it works only with `[AnyObject]`

```
override class func ignoredProperties() -> [AnyObject] {
    return ["arrivalToShow", "departureToShow"]
}
```